# Only apply a CSS rule in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

How can I make the `margin-top : -5%;` apply **only** in Firefox?

In this code:

```
#snap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -5%; // only apply in Firefox
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the `margin-top` to only apply to other browsers, and not to Firefox?

Comment: Yes, not show only FF :)

Comment: May I ask why you don't want this to show in Firefox?

Comment: The reason is that on Firefox browser, a content div moves everything right, however in other browsers like Chrome I see the content DIV as I will, I tried in other ways and do not satisfy me.

Comment: What about using http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ ? 
It should fix the browser dependency.

Comment: You can use RESS (Responsive Design with Server Side elements) to ensure that a given style declaration only applies in Firefox, but I suspect that all you need is a CSS Reset - to ensure that you start off with the same margins and paddings in all browsers.

Comment: You're right, I wanted to avoid, but I think I'll just make the code with Bootstrap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be this works. It's a hack for Firefox that worked years ago. Have not tested it with latest Firefox.

```
  @-moz-document url-prefix() { 
      #snap {
         margin-top: -5%;
            }
  }
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/

Answer (score 9):

You could use `@supports` to hack it.

> Allows native feature detection, similar to Modernizr, using @supports

In the code below, `margin-top: -50px` will be applied to the `div` if `-moz-transform: translate(0, 0)` is supported on a browser.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

@supports (-moz-transform: translate(0, 0)) {
  div {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```